# Javascript Module Pattern and Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, drupal, google-closure-compiler

I am using the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) on a Drupal project right now.  My Javascript is structured using the [Javascript Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).

Because of the way Drupal works, I am compiling each JS file individually.  Simple Compilation mode works well, but I would like to use [Advanced Compilation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) on each file.

My files are all variations on

```
var FOO = (function(me, $, Drupal, undefined) {
  function init (context, settings) {
    do_sutff();
  };

  Drupal.behaviors['FOO'] = {
    attach: init
  };

  return me;
}(FOO || {}, jQuery, Drupal));
```

My problem is that `Drupal.behaviors` is a specific object in Drupal, and the `attach` property also is a specific property.  When a Drupal page renders, `Drupal.behaviors` gets looped through, and all of the `attach` functions are called with the proper arguments.  In other words, I don't want *anything* renamed with the Drupal object.

When I use Advanced Compilation mode, I get

```
var c = function(a, d, b) {
  b.b.FOO = {a:function() {
    do_stuff()
  }};
  return a
}(c || {}, jQuery, Drupal);
```

I have tried many variations on trying to get the compiler to recognize the whole `Drupal` object as an extern without luck.  No matter what I try, `.behaviors` and `.attach` always get renamed.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to keep its hands off an entire object?

Comment: i get b.behaviors.FOO={attach:function(){}}; ...

Comment: @dandavis  I get that with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS. When I use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, the `Drupal` object gets manhandled, as the edit shows.

Comment: var o=Drupal['behaviors']['FOO']; o['attach']=init;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no concept "Don't modify any properties on this object". You can however setup an extern such as:

```
/** @interface */
function DrupalBehavior() {}
DrupalBehavior.prototype.attach = function(){};

/** @constructor */
function DrupalObject () {}

/** @type {Object.<string, DrupalBehavior>} */    
DrupalObject.prototype.behaviors = {};
```

Then, in your code:

```
var FOO = (
   /**
    * @param {Object} me
    * @param {jQuery} $
    * @param {DrupalObject} Drupal
    * @param {*=} undefined
    */
   function(me, $, Drupal, undefined) {
     function init (context, settings) {
       do_sutff();
     };
     Drupal.behaviors['FOO'] = {
       attach: init
     };

     return me;
  }(FOO || {}, jQuery, Drupal));
```

In this case the Drupal argument will be renamed, but the `behaviors` property and its associated `attach` sub-property will not be.

One note on jQuery: You are passing the jQuery namespace object into the function as a 
parameter. Closure-compiler does not trace the type well in this object. The annotation I have listed would be for an instace of the jQuery object as opposed to the entire jQuery namespace. This is probably not what you intended. The only type-safe way to handle this in Closure-compiler is NOT to pass namespaces through function closure.

Update: After looking through the JavaScript Module Pattern post you linked, they encourage passing global namespace objects into function closures. This pattern has known problems with Closure-compiler. You will need to choose to either follow the pattern in this regard or opt for full compatibility with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this tomorrow.  Is the last paragraph true when jQuery is in noConflict mode?  That is the reason for the parameter.

Comment: Yes. The way to handle this is with Closure-compiler's `output_wrapper` option. You would use something like: `--output_wrapper="(function(jQuery){%output%})(jQuery.noConflict())"`